# iOS: Present View Controller destroys UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm presenting modally another `UIViewController` inside a view controller. The original view controller consists of two collection views, both of which have some cells that contain image subviews. When the new view controller is presented, these two collection views are 'destroyed'; that is, the images inside these collection views cannot be viewed anymore and the cell structures and layout of these collection views are destroyed as well.

But I would like to keep the collection views; that is, after I dismiss the presented view controller, I would be able to see the collection views without change, as if the view controller has never been presented before.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Give us a code of viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear of your first view controller.

Comment: Hmm, none of them is written in the first view controller...

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different view controllers. I mean that first vc is original, not presented view controller. This methods are called when you present/dismiss another vc